# Problem with Alert in the Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, alert

How can I do to verify or assert an alert with a message that contains 
a variable in this text?

For example, I have to capture a alert with this message:  Answer number (var 
`id_answer`) successfully accepted.  id_answer is the variable and I don't know this value before the alert  is show. This alert is triggered for a flash[:notice] command in a controller, for example (in Rails). And I need to simulate the click in the button ok inside alert window  with a selenium command too.  Is it possible?

Anyone can help me with this with a example for a complete syntax command in Selenium IDE for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

to simulate the click in the buton OK you could use command assertAlert - Getting an alert has the same effect as manually clicking OK. If an alert is generated but you do not consume it with getAlert, the next Selenium action will fail.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [getAlert](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-remote-control/0.9.0/doc/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/Selenium.html):

"Retrieves the message of a JavaScript alert generated during the previous action, or fail if there were no alerts."