# can I handle java-script validation in selenium IDE 1.5.0 & how?

Tags: javascript, ide, selenium

I want to record JS validation in Selenium IDE 1.5.0

I was unable to handle these validation so plz tell me how can i record it in IDE.

Comment: In which way the errors are being presented? Are they presented as text or displayed as alert or...? Give us more details of this issue.

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348775/problem-with-alert-in-the-selenium-ide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I am facing this issue (exactly: having to click OK at confirm box) and **assertConfirmation()** works for me. Selenium confirms and the script goes on.